# Executar arquivos SQL dentro de subdiretórios no Linux

Tags: mysql, sql, linux

Eu tenho um repositório de arquivos SQL onde cada um representa uma *stored procedure*. Estes arquivos estão dentro de um diretório organizados em outros subdiretórios.

Exemplo da minha estrutura de diretórios:

```
stored-procedures
---d1
------sd1
---------sp1.sql
---------sp2.sql
---------sp3.sql
------sd2
---------sp4.sql
---------sp5.sql
------sd3
---d2
------sd4
---------sp6.sql
---d3
------sd5
------sd6
```

O comando que utilizo para executar cada stored-procedure separadamente é o seguinte:

```
mysql -uuser -psenha bd < sp1.sql --force
```

Como eu poderia fazer isto no Linux através da linha de comando ou criação de um *script*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui construir o meu próprio script da seguinte forma:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
echo '...'

if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
    echo "Favor definir dois parâmetros para execução deste script"
    echo "Primeiro parâmetro:"
    echo "      nome do usuário do banco de dados"
    echo "Segundo parâmetro:"
    echo "      senha do usuário do banco de dados"
    echo "Execução interrompida"
    echo '...'
    exit 1
fi

echo "Iniciando a execução das stored-procedures no diretório /var/www/stored-procedures"
for file in /var/www/stored-procedures/**/*.sql
do
    echo $file
    mysql -u$1 -p$2 banco_de_dados < $file --force  
done
echo "Execução do script finalizada"
echo '...'
```

Obs 1: Como parâmetro o usuário deve passar o usuário e a senha do banco de dados que contém as stored procedures.

Obs 2: O diretório utilizado foi o `/var/www/stored-procedures` mas basta alterar este trecho de código para o seu diretório que contenha as stored-procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que sua árvore de diretórios seja algo como:

```
$ tree stored-procedures/
stored-procedures/
|-- d1
|   |-- sd1
|   |   |-- sp1.sql
|   |   |-- sp2.sql
|   |   `-- sp3.sql
|   |-- sd2
|   |   |-- sp4.sql
|   |   `-- sp5.sql
|   `-- sd3
|-- d2
|   `-- sd4
|       `-- sp6.sql
`-- d3
    |-- sd5
    `-- sd6

15 directories, 0 files
```

Você pode usar o utilitario `find` para resolver o seu problema:

```
$ find ./stored-procedures/ -name "*.sql" -exec mysql -uuser -psenha bd -e \"source {}\" \;
```